# Is there a way to get enode:// addresses of etherscan and infura nodes?

Tags: etherscan, infura, enode

How can I get enode:// addresses of Infura and Etherscan nodes? Both mainnet and ropsten ones preferably. I would like to add them to my nodes peers list to be able to sync better.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Etherscan and infura do not publish an enode list, and you can only connect to them by chance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link to nodes List 
 https://etherscan.io/nodetracker/nodes
Cheers!!!

Comment: This tels the nodes Etherscan see but not their enode url.

Comment: There is a way to get the `enode` using the copy button on the right hand side.